# C socket programming - printf does not print anything on the screen

Tags: c, sockets

I am new to unix socket programming. I haven't found myself a comfortable book or tutorial and so I am really struggling.

Here is the program code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(){

    printf("one");
    int socketHandle, newSocketHandle, portno;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress, clientAddress;


    printf("two");


    portno = 5001;
    bzero((char *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portno);

    printf("three");

    //creating the socket
    socketHandle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socketHandle < 0){
        perror("ERROR : Socket not created.");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Socket created.");





    //binding the socket
    if(bind(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0){
        perror("ERROR : Socket not binded.");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Socket binded.");

    //make the socket listen
    listen(socketHandle, 5);

    int len = sizeof(clientAddress);
    //accept the connection requests
    newSocketHandle = accept(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &len);
    if(newSocketHandle < 0){
        perror("ERROR : Connection not accepted.");
    }

    printf("Connection accepted.");
    return 0;
}
```

(I tried to print `one`, `two`, and `three` for debugging)

But, even the `printf("one")` in the first line doesn't work. **The cursor just keeps blinking** (indicating that the program is still in execution). I can't even get a clue of what is going wrong in the above program. Using the `bzero()` function also throws a warning saying

```
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bzero’ [enabled by default]
```

I find socket programming difficult as different websites show different code. Also, please suggest any good tutorial on C/C++ socket programming.

Comment: `serverAddress` is not initialised. You are trying to bind to a random address. Which fails, obviously.

Comment: @wildplasser I added the second code snippet trying to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I find it hard to read out of sequence code. BTW: I don't see a `bzero()` anywhere in the code.

Comment: @wildplasser Sorry, I missed it out. Edited my code now.

Comment: Make sure to print a newline also in your debug messages for them to show immediately. example `printf("one\n");`

Comment: @ErikEkman That had been the problem. I've added a bold statement to the question description now. Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Bind errors have nothing to do with `printf()`, and `printf()` has nothing to do with socket programming. I suggest you sort out what your question is actually about, and re-title and re-word it appropriately.

Comment: @EJP At the time of posting this question, I did not have a clue of what was going wrong AS I HAD MENTIONED IN THE QUESTION DESCRIPTION. However, as you suggested, I've changed the description now and the title was rephrased already. BTW, there is also an `upvote` option in SO :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to print a newline in your debug messages for them to show immediately.

Example `printf("one\n");`

If you really don't want newlines you can instead flush output with `fflush(stdout);`.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use the Beej's guide to network programming as a starting point and use it's sample codes :
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/print/bgnet_USLetter.pdf

Comment: +1 Thanks for the book. Learning socket programming from it now :)